# USB Linux distro using only initrd.gz

Tags: linux, usb, bootable

I am working on a very small Linux distro which is designed to boot off an Android phone using DriveDroid.  Boot time must be minimal, and the distro needs to be loaded to RAM so the phone can be disconnected.  I don't need Xorg or anything more than basic system utilities and Python, so I'm curious as to if it would be possible to just put everything in the initrd.gz file (no filesystem.squashfs or cloop file).  Are there any pitfalls or issues that may come up that I should be aware of?  Thank you for any input you have.